# magmi import all images in specific path

Tags: magento, import, magmi

I installed Magmi for Magento on my Magento Test Environment (1.9.2.4) and tried to import multiple images for item with the 'media_gallery' field. Its worked as expected.

Now I try to find a way to import all the images in a specific path.

For example:
Item SKU is 001 so I place all the images that related to item 001 in a directory with the following path - media/import/001
I would like to type under 'media_gallery' something like '001/*' so it will import all the images inside 001 directory.

Off course it wasn't so intuitive and didn't work when I typed '001/*'.

So before I jump into Magmi plugin development, is there an easiest way to import all the images in a specific path as image gallery?

Comment: Did you try image path like /001/imagename.jpg in csv file?

Comment: Yes @Muk I did and it works.
What I looking for is to import via the media_gallery field an unknown number of images with unknown names.

For example item 001 have 2 images named 001_1.jpg, 001_2.jpg
and item 002 have 3 images named 002_1.jpg, 002_2.jpg and 002_3.jpg.

In this case I don't want to write image by image into the csv but would like to "ask" from magmi to import all the images available in specific path.

something like:

<?php
    foreach (scandir('/path/to/001') as $image) {
        // magmi add $image
    }
?>

Comment: Do you want to import multiple images as gallery images for a single product? If yes you may write comma separated values under media_gallery column